# Compare Two JSONArray In Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, compare

I want to compare two JSONArray with the same value with different order how compare it. This code work fine if value place in the same index.

```
String a = "[\"ABC-110101-056079-0001\",\"CBA-111101-056079-0001\",\"BCD-110101-056079-0011\"]";
String b = "[\"ABC-111101-056079-0001\",\"CBA-110101-056079-0001\",\"BCD-110101-056079-0011\"]";

JSONArray jsonArraya = null;
JSONArray jsonArrayb = null;
try {
    jsonArraya = new JSONArray(a);
    jsonArrayb = new JSONArray(b);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (jsonArraya.equals(jsonArrayb)) {
    Log.i("TAG",str2 is equal to str1 = " + "true");
}
```

Comment: i think you have to get all of their children and compare them one by one

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in this situation is to parse values of those arrays first using `Gson` into `POJO` files, After that create `.equals()` method, which will add all strings from array into `Set<>`. 
Then `iterate` over one set and remove all current item from another set and remove the same elements. Both objects are the same if at the end there will be no elements in the second set.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the elements of each array to a `SortedSet` instance and compare those:

```
SortedSet<Object> seta = new TreeSet<>();
jsonArraya.forEach(seta::add);

SortedSet<Object> setb = new TreeSet<>();
jsonArrayb.forEach(setb::add);

Log.i("TAG", "str2 is equal to str1 = " + seta.equals(setb));
```